# When a template is instantiated?

Tags: c++, template-instantiation

The fact that a `template` is not instantiated until it is used so for example if I have this class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct Pow{
    T operator()(T const& x) const{ return x * x; }
};

void func(Pow<double>); // Pow<double> instantiated here?
void func(Pow<int>){}   // Pow<int> instantiated here?

int main(){
    Pow<int> pi; // instantiated here?
    func(pi); // Pow<int> instantiated here
}
```

- So when exactly the template is instantiated?
- So is `Pow<int>` instantiated when `func(Pow<int>)` is declared?
- If I didn't use `Pow<int>` in `main()` then has it been instantiated because of its usage in `func` as the the type of its parameters?

Comment: The topic of when a template is instantiated is a very complicated, complex and nuanced problem. That's all I am going to say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general rule for implicit instantiation of class templates is as follows

> **[temp.inst]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.inst#2) Unless a class template specialization is a declared specialization, the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program. [...]

That in conjunction with this requirement about functions:

> **[dcl.fct.def.general]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct.def#general-2) In a function-definition, either void declarator ; or declarator ; shall be a well-formed function declaration as described in [dcl.fct]. A function shall be defined only in namespace or class scope. **The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be a (possibly cv-qualified) class type that is incomplete or abstract within the function body unless the function is deleted ([dcl.fct.def.delete]).**

Tells us all we need to know to examine your program. Functions declarations don't require the class type to be complete. So...

> `Pow<double>` instantiated here?

No. This is a function declaration that is not a definition. It does not require a complete class type for a parameter. `Pow<double>` is not implicitly instantiated.

> `Pow<int>` instantiated here?

Yes. This is a function definition, and so an instantiation is required.

> `Pow<int> pi;` // instantiated here?

Was already instantiated due to the function.

> So when exactly the template is instantiated?

Strictly when required in a way that affects the semantics of the program.

> So is `Pow<int>` instantiated when `func(Pow<int>)` is declared?

When `func(Pow<int>)` is *defined*.

> If I didn't use `Pow<int>` in `main()` then has it been instantiated because of its usage in `func` as the the type of its parameters?

Yes, because you did so in a function *definition*.

Comment: Ok  got it thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

In your example it is instantiated when compiler sees creation of an object of your template class:

```
Pow<int> pi;
```

C++ standard says:

> 17.8.1 Implicit instantiation [temp.inst]
>
> 1 Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly
> instantiated (17.8.2) or explicitly specialized (17.8.3), the class
> template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the
> specialization is referenced in a context that requires a
> completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class
> type affects the semantics of the program...

Comment: Thank you so much.