When does type traits instantiate templates
Why doesn't the static_assert inside Foo get triggered in the following code ?
Doesn't the type trait inside if constexpr need to instantiate Foo<float> & Foo<char> ?
https://godbolt.org/z/zTPqxvr6e
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int>);
};

int main()
{
    using X = Foo<float>;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<X, Foo<char>>)
    {
        std::cout << "Yes\n";
    }
    return 0;
}


This might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/q/69652544/817643

if constexpr (std::is_same_v<X, Foo<char>>) can only be use within the template, not in "normal code"

@PepijnKramer Why ? And what do you mean by "normal code" ?

It seems I am slightly mistaken, if constexpr can be use outside a template (but its use is more limited). But I also never needed it (and I have done a lot of template meta programming). Now  that I look longer at your question I also understand better what you're trying to ask (not that I have an answer to that)

@PepjinKramer afaik i can be used outside of templates but there the false branch is not discarded

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah, that's the bit that confused me and why I never use constexpr if outside templates.

False branch of constexpr if is checked (that is, it must be syntactically correct and well-formed), and then discarded (that is, doesn't contribute to gerenated object/executable file even at the lowest optimization level, where ordinary false branches still remain). Exploited here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79197794/11102572. I suppose, names refered in discarded branch do not count as ODR-used too...

Class template is implicitly instantiated when the compiler needs that class to be complete:

https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#2
Unless a class template specialization is a declared specialization, the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program.

None of the expressions in that example requires complete Foo<T>, so it's never instantiated.
using X = Foo<float>; is just a declaration. And there's no reason why is_same<X, Foo<char>> might need the definition of its arguments.
You may simply remove the definition of struct Foo, and the example will still be well-formed.
